# iPhone floating header element like native app

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

How can i have a section in iPhone web site(header) to remain in a fixed position and rest of the site to scroll(preventDefault or watever) so that it behaves like a native app...any safari api's or javascript that i can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the solution for you:  **[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)** *by Matteo Spinelli* ([Demo](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll/index.html?v=3.7.1))

> *The overflow:scroll for mobile webkit.
>   Project started because webkit for
>   iPhone does not provide a native way
>   to scroll content inside a fixed size
>   (width/height) div. So basically it
>   was impossible to have a fixed
>   header/footer and a scrolling central
>   area. Until now.*

Comment: thnks buddy...this was what i was lookin for ...thnks loads.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that right you want an element staying at a fixed position? Have you tried creating a div and setting it's css attribute position to fixed? See here: [CSS Property Position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: i actually want only that div to remain there while the rest of the site can be scrollable...like in a native app...tried fixed position, did not work...

Comment: Hmm.. But actually it should. If you have the DIV as, for example the first element and declare it's position as fixed, then the rest of your site should scroll as it always does and the other DIV remains on the top. But maybe the solution provided by @galambalazs will also fit you needs, although I think that it might be too much overhead if you really only want one element fixed and the others scrolling.